# Sorting the data from oracle database into different sheets

Tags: excel, oracle10g, vba

Following is the VBA code to fetch data from oracle database to excel.
Instead of the data going to some random sheet I want the data related to collabname 301_CBCompanySync_SAP_to_HHT to be gone into a sheet named 301_CBCompanySync_SAP_to_HHT and the

data related to the collabname 302_CBCustomer_SAP_to_HHT to be gone into sheet named "302_CBCustomer_SAP_to_HHT" ..so on

How shall I modify the below code

```
 Sub Load_data()

        Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim col As Integer
        Dim row As Integer
        Dim Query As String
        Dim mtxData As Variant


        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

     cn.Open ( _
    "User ID=xxxx" & _
    ";Password=xxxxx" & _
    ";Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/xxxxxx" & _
    ";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")


Dim arrayCollabName As Variant
Dim idx As Integer
idx = 0
arrayCollabName = Array("301_CBCompanySync_SAP_to_HHT", "302_CBCustomer_SAP_to_HHT", "303_CustomerExclusionList_SAP_to_HHT")


  For idx = 0 To 2

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets.Add

    rs.Open "select COLLABNAME,DATETIME,TOTALFLOWS,SUCCFLOWS,FAILEDFLOWS from EWS_COLLAB WHERE COLLABNAME like '" & arrayCollabName(idx) & "'", cn


        col = 0
        Do While col < rs.Fields.Count
            .Cells(1, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col).Name
            col = col + 1
        Loop
        mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData

    End With
    rs.Close

  Next

cn.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, hope its ok.

```
Sub Load_data()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim Query As String
    Dim mtxData As Variant
    Dim arrayCollabName As Variant
    Dim idx As Integer

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
idx = 0
'array with all collab names
arrayCollabName = Array("301_CBCompanySync_SAP_to_HHT", "302_CBCustomer_SAP_to_HHT", "303_CustomerExclusionList_SAP_to_HHT")

'connect to Database
 cn.Open ( _
"User ID=xxxx" & _
";Password=xxxxx" & _
";Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/xxxxxx" & _
";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")

'loop for inserting the Data from the SQL
For idx = 0 To 2
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets.Add
    'Rename the new added sheet
    If Len(arrayCollabName(idx)) > 31 Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = Left(arrayCollabName(idx), 31)
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Name = arrayCollabName(idx)
    End If
    'database query
    rs.Open "select COLLABNAME,DATETIME,TOTALFLOWS,SUCCFLOWS,FAILEDFLOWS from EWS_COLLAB WHERE COLLABNAME like '" & arrayCollabName(idx) & "'", cn


    col = 0
    Do While col < rs.Fields.Count
        .Cells(1, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col).Name
        col = col + 1
    Loop
    mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
    .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData

    End With
    'database query with the search results closing
    rs.Close
Next
'database connection closed
cn.Close
End Sub

    Sub deletSheets()
        Dim idx As Integer
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For idx = 0 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
            If Not ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
                ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
            End If
        Next idx
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thx a lot, but one of my collabName has more than 31 characters so I am getting an error, Is there any way to truncate the collabname to 31 characters and display it as sheet name.

Comment: There is again a problem, once I run the macro now the sheets are populating with collabnames, but when I run the macro again  it says "Cannot rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet, a referenced object library or a workbook referenced by VisualBasic"

Can I add any code in the macro that initially deletes all the sheets and again populate the sheets?

Comment: The above Delete old Sheets is deleting all the sheet except the first sheet named "301_CBCompanySync_SAP_to_HHT", so I am still getting the above error, Any way to change this sheet name to "Sheet1" through the code at the end of "Delete old Sheet method"

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now its all complete with no errors. Can you tell me whether I closed this connection perfectly in the code?

Comment: should be ok with the closing

Comment: For idx = 0 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 2
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Next idx
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"

Here the data is stored from the previous run in Sheet1, any way I can delete all the data in Sheet 1 before proceeding further in the code?

Comment: Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents

Comment: I want to delete all the sheets except sheet1 which has all the formulae to do my calculations, any code so that sheet1 is not deleted and all the sheets are added to it with their own collabnames. When I rerun the macro it should first delte all the sheets except sheet1